# Removing grid in scanned/photographed medical Documents

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I'm a dental student and currently trying to write a script for analyzing and extracting handwritten digits from dental records. I already have a rough version of the script finished but my recognition rate is pretty low. A big problem with analyzing the data is a grid that proves difficult to remove.

Scanned form that I want to analyse (white fields are for anonymity):

[image]

Empty form:
[image]

I've tried different solutions for this problem (Erosion/Dilation, HoughLineTransform and susbtraction of the Lines).
Using featurematching and substracting with an empty template currently give me the best results.

Results:

[image]

Eroding and dilating this image gives even better results

Results:
![][4]

But this needs a new calibration nearly every time i try it.
Do you know of a more elegant solution to my problem.
Could SURF matching give better results?
Thank you very much!

Here's my code so far:

```
GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15

def match_img_to_template(input_img, template_img, MAX_FEATURES, GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT):

    # blurring of the input image
    template_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(template_img, (3, 3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

    # equalizing the histogramm of the input image
    img_preprocessed = cv2.equalizeHist(input_img)

    # ORB Detector
    orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_FEATURES)
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img_preprocessed, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(template_img, None)

    # Brute Force Matching
    matcher= cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
    matches = matcher.match(des1, des2, None)

    matches.sort(key=lambda x:x.distance, reverse=False)

    numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
    matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]

    # Remove not so good matches
    numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
    matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]

    # Extract location of good matches
    points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        points1[i, :] = kp1[match.queryIdx].pt
        points2[i, :] = kp2[match.trainIdx].pt

    # Find homography
    h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)

    # Use homography
    height, width = template_img.shape
    input_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(input_img, h, (width, height))

    ret1, input_warped_thresh = cv2.threshold(input_warped,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    diff = cv2.absdiff(template_img, input_warped_thresh)

    ret, diff = cv2.threshold(diff, 20, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    diff = cv2.equalizeHist(diff)

    # Create kernels
    kernel1 = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
    kernel2 = np.ones((6,6), np.uint8)
    # erode dilate to remove the grid
    diff_erode = cv2.erode(diff,kernel1)
    diff_dilated = cv2.dilate(diff_erode,kernel2)
    # invert diff_dilate
    diff_dilated_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(diff_dilated)

    return diff_dilated_inv
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by "new calibration"? Adjusting parameters?

Comment: Hi Sushi,
i mean that i have to adjust the erode/dilate and threshold parameters pretty often when inputting different images.
Currently im using scanned images which are pretty "normalized", but i want to input webcam pictures for ease of use and increased speed. My method needs a lot of finetuning whenever for example the lighting changes

Comment: You can use this approach to extract the document and from the background assuming that the background is darker. Later substract the empty form. Then binarize it using OTSU thresholding and apply opening operation to get rid of the remaining edges. Later use findContours function to get your marks. Then you can check the area of each contour and eliminate those which area is lower than threshold.